# Pointer and address issue in C

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose that in the main function an int type varaible x has a value 20. IF the function is called 2 times as foo(&x) , whats the value of x?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void foo(int *n)
{ 
int *m;
m = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*m = 10;
*m = (*m)*5;
n = m;
}
int main() 
{
    int x = 20;
    foo(&x);
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Shouldn't the value of x be 50 since we are initializing the address of n with m which has the value 50 but its coming out to be 20?

Comment: with `n = m` you make the **local** pointer `n` point to the same place as `m`. Changes to `n` inside the `foo()` function **are not reflected** in `x` in `main()`; changes to `*n` are reflected in `x`. You probably want `*n = *m;` instead ... and remember to `free(m);` when you're done with it ... and `#include <stdlib.h>` [and stop casting the return value of `malloc()`].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *address* of the `n` pointer is local to `foo`. So modifying the *pointer* inside `foo` has no effect outside of the function. But when dereferencing `n`, the *pointed-to* value can be changed.

For `x` to become 50, the last line of the `foo` function should have been:

```
*n = *m;
```